# How to simplify return value using Regex?

Tags: javascript, json

I've used Imgur API and it worked, the problem is it returns data with all parameters, it looks like:

```
{"data":{"id":"TjJuJ29","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1403695169,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1538,"height":839,"size":733684,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"deletehash":"lCqsN0tKqWyJFET","link":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/TjJuJ29.jpg"},"success":true,"status":200}
```

I need to know what's correct Regex to convert it into simple Link URL and forget other parameters. I'm using Javascript.

Expected output would look like: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoW2K.jpg**

Thanks!

EDIT: It's JSON, my mistake.

Comment: Huh? Is this some kind of joke?

Comment: Uhhhmhmmm.. Why regex???

Comment: Don't. It's JSON, so you `JSON.parse` to convert it into a javascript object and then just access its properties. `myParsedObject.data.link`

Comment: Oops, it seems JSON. Sorry! Thanks for clearing up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use a regex.

Assuming your variable is stored like this:

```
var myResult = {"data":{"id":"TjJuJ29","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1403695169,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1538,"height":839,"size":733684,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"deletehash":"lCqsN0tKqWyJFET","link":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/TjJuJ29.jpg"},"success":true,"status":200}
```

Then, just use this to get the link:

```
myResult.data.link
```

The result appears to be nothing more than a [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).
However,if it's a JSON string, you may need to use `JSON.parse()`, first:

```
var myResult = JSON.parse('{"data":{"id":"TjJuJ29","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1403695169,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":1538,"height":839,"size":733684,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"deletehash":"lCqsN0tKqWyJFET","link":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/TjJuJ29.jpg"},"success":true,"status":200}');
```

Comment: If it's originally a string, you might need to `JSON.parse` first.

Comment: @MattBurland: Yea, added that to my answer.